# installation problem with epftoolbox in python

Tags: python, installation, epf

I have absolute no further idea, how i could manage the installation of the epftoolbox in python. I have tried the steps from https://epftoolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/started.html in various ways and directions, but it still doesn't work and i get the following error when running the file:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'epftoolbox.evaluation'`

Can anyone suggest a step by step video or something like that, where the installation is showed for 'dummies'?

Any help would be veeeeery appreciated!

PS: I'm working with pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with pycharm first create a new project with a virtual environment and open the terminal and type the following clone statement : git clone https://github.com/jeslago/epftoolbox.git

then move to the cloned directory by typing this command:
cd epftoolbox
once your'e inside this directory run your pip install command:
pip install .

you should be able to work with the library here.
since you already created the virtual environment..

Hope it solved your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).